# How to install and run the acme.sh inside AWS lambda?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am interested to run this [acme.sh](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh) a LetsEncrypt bash client within AWS Lambda to generate a ECDSA wildcard SSL cert.

I read that AWS [lambda now supports bash](https://github.com/gkrizek/bash-lambda-layer) via [Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

The documentation within AWS Lambda developer guide doesn't really paint a clear picture for me to do this.

So I was wondering if somebody can help make the developer guide clearer for me in this particular context.

Answer (score 2):

This script is a bit heavy for lambda, id suggest trying to use AWS Fargate instead, which lets you spin up dynamic containers, there's a Dockerfile already in the repo, so start from there.

Comment: How do you tell that it's too "heavy"? I like to learn more abt the way you understand this situation.

Comment: looking at the Dockerfile its needs these corelibs to function
  openssl \ coreutils \bind-tools   curl \  socat \ tzdata \ tar \
So you can make your own container for lambda, since it is running shell scripts, instead of code scripts like python or node, which lambda is more suited for.

Comment: Thanks! I use your hint to google around more and I found this comment which I think is promising for my situation. https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh/issues/1368#issuecomment-372954665 I am not so good with AWS. Can help me decipher the two ways suggested by the comments? A lot of AWS lingo was used.

Comment: yea they effectively say the same thing that use faragte to launch a docker image, and have that run your commands, they say to store cert on amazon S3 so it can always be accessed. 

I would build the image locally, and test it out there, then move it to fargate

Info on fargate:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted_Fargate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) (that is written with python) on AWS Lambda using python runtime to generate wildcard SSL certs using [DNS challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge).

You can also check the complete [certbot-lambda](https://github.com/KiraLT/certbot-lambda) script that generates certs and exports them to [AWS](AWS Secrets Manager).